# sharepoint - starting workflow jsom script works on premise but fails online?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-workflow, csom, sharepoint-jsom

I have a piece of javascript code starting a workflow. 
It all works on my on premise dev machine. 
But as soon as I try to run it on an online site, it fails.

It is based on the workflow.asmx web service, and I get error 500 - value does not fall on expected range...

I suspect this is in the workflow parameters. But I cannot see what exactly. The user login differs but it is compliant with oneline format...

Any idea about any possible differences between on premise vs online that might explain this?

just in case, here's my code (again, perfectly fine onpremise):

```
function StartMyWorkflow(listGUID, itemId) {

     var wfDefinitionId = "{9279E1FF-1D32-4423-85B7-C7F21998A701}";

     var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
     var web = ctx.get_web();
     var list = web.get_lists().getById(listGUID);
     var item = list.getItemById(itemId);
     var currentUser = web.get_currentUser();

     ctx.load(web);
     ctx.load(item);
     ctx.load(currentUser);

     ctx.executeQueryAsync(
         Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
             var login = currentUser.get_loginName();
             var name = currentUser.get_title();
             var xml = getWFAssocData(name, login);

             var fileRef = "https://" + location.host +     item.get_item("FileRef");

             $().SPServices({
                 operation: "StartWorkflow",
                 item: fileRef,
                 templateId: wfDefinitionId,
                 workflowParameters: xml,
                 completefunc: function () {
                     SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('workflow started', false);                    
                 }
             });
         }), 
         function (s, a) { console.error(a.get_message());}
      );
}


function getWFAssocData(name, login) {
     var assocData = '<dfs:myFields           xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:dms="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/documentManagement/types" xmlns:dfs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/dataFormSolution" xmlns:q="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2009/WSSList/queryFields" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2009/WSSList/dataFields" xmlns:ma="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/metadata/properties/metaAttributes" xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">' +
                '<dfs:queryFields></dfs:queryFields>' +
                '<dfs:dataFields>' +
                '<d:SharePointListItem_RW>' +
                '<d:Approvers>' +
                '<d:Assignment>' +
                '<d:Assignee>' +
                '<pc:Person><pc:DisplayName>' + name + '</pc:DisplayName><pc:AccountId>' + login + '</pc:AccountId><pc:AccountType>User</pc:AccountType></pc:Person>' +
                '</d:Assignee>' +
                '<d:Stage xsi:nil="true" />' +
                '<d:AssignmentType>Serial</d:AssignmentType>' +
                '</d:Assignment>' +
                '</d:Approvers>' +
                '<d:ExpandGroups>true</d:ExpandGroups>' +
                '<d:NotificationMessage>Please approve <a href="#1">test</a></d:NotificationMessage>' +
                '<d:DueDateforAllTasks xsi:nil="true" /><d:DurationforSerialTasks xsi:nil="true" />' +
                '<d:DurationUnits>Day</d:DurationUnits>' +
                '<d:CC />' +
                '<d:CancelonRejection>true</d:CancelonRejection>' +
                '<d:CancelonChange>false</d:CancelonChange>' +
                '<d:EnableContentApproval>false</d:EnableContentApproval>' +
                '</d:SharePointListItem_RW>' +
                '</dfs:dataFields>' +
                '</dfs:myFields>';

     return assocData;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be as silly as obvious. I was just missing a 's' in the fileRef url... I've corrected the above script, so it's actually fully functional.